# How to use BETWEEN Operator with Text Value in SQL?

Tags: sql

How am I going to use BETWEEN Operator with Text Value or what is the right syntax when you will select all products with a ProductName for example ending with any of the letter BETWEEN 'C' and 'M'?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If this is going to be a common query, it may be worth investigating whether your database system (e.g. SQL Server, mysql, Oracle, etc) has features that would make an index possible for this query - e.g. function-based indexes or indexed computed columns. To know that, though, we'd need to know which system you're using.

Comment: I'm trying to code it on w3schools code generator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most SQL dialects provide the `RIGHT()` function.  This allows you to do:

```
WHERE RIGHT(TextValue, 1) BETWEEN 'C' AND 'M'
```

If your database doesn't have this function, you can do something similar with the built-in functions.  Also, the exact comparison might depend on the collation of the column/table/database/server.  Sometimes comparisons are independent of case and sometimes they are dependent on case.

Comment: Why there's an error occured when I ran it on w3sschools?

Comment: Seems like it's correct but it's not running on w3Schools.

Comment: Seems like the w3sschools dbms doesn't support the RIGHT function.

Comment: @user3783598 . . . It looks like they are running Oracle on the backend.  The equivalent in Oracle is:  `substr(customername, length(customername), 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are interested in an alternative method (which does work with the w3schools SQL editor), you can also use the `LIKE` operator:

```
WHERE ProductName LIKE '%[c-m]'
```

This will get you all Product Names ending on any character between C and M.
(It does work with the w3schools SQL Editor.)

In this case, the `LIKE` operator is using two wildcard characters:

1.%

> Any string of zero or more characters.

2.[c-m]

> Any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set
>   ([abcdef]).

You can find more information about the `LIKE` operator here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx